# Does MYSQL stores it in an optimal way it if the same string is stored in multiple rows?

Tags: mysql, database, storage

I have a table where one of the columns is a sort of id string used to group several rows from the table. Let's say the column name is "map" and one of the values for map is e.g. "walmart". The column has an index on it, because I use to it filter those rows which belong to a certain map.

I have lots of such maps and I don't know how much space the different map values take up from the table. Does MYSQL recognizes the same map value is stored for multiple rows and stores it only once internally and only references it with an internal numeric id?

Or do I have to replace the map string with a numeric id explicitly and use a different table to pair map strings to ids if I want to decrease the size of the table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MySQL will store the whole data for every row, regardless of whether the data already exists in a different row.

If you have a limited set of options, you could use an ENUM field, else you could pull the names into another table and join on it.

Comment: Strange MYSQL can't do it. It has an index on the column, so it could know if a value is used several times. I'll look into the options then.

Answer (score 0):

I think MySQL will duplicate your content each time : it stores data row by row, unless you explicitly specify otherwise (putting the data in another table, like you suggested).

Using another table will mean you need to add a JOIN in some of your queries : you might want to think a bit about the size of your data *(are they that big ?)*, compared to the *(small ?)* performance loss you may encounter because of that join.

Another solution would be using an [ENUM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/enum.html) datatype, at least if you know in advance which string you will have in your table, and there are only a few of those.

Finally, another solution might be to store an integer "code" corresponding to the strings, and have those code translated to strings by your application, totally outside of the database (or use some table to store the correspondances, but have that table cached by your application, instead of using joins in SQL queries).

It would not be as "clean", but might be better for performances -- still, this may be some kind of micro-optimization that is not necessary in your case...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the same values over and over again, then there is a good functional reason to move it to a separate table, totally aside from disk space considerations: To avoid problems with inconsistent data.

Suppose you have a table of Stores, which includes a column for StoreName. Among the values in StoreName "WalMart" occurs 300 times, and then there's a "BalMart". Is that just a typo for "WalMart", or is that a different store?

Also, if there's other data associated with a store that would be constant across the chain, you should store it just once and not repeatedly.

Of course, if you're just showing locations on a map and you really don't care what they are, it's just a name to display, then this would all be irrelevant.

And if that's the case, then buying a bigger disk is probably a simpler solution than redesigning your database just to save a few bytes per record. Because if we're talking arbitrary strings for place names here, then trying to find duplicates and have look-ups for them is probably a lot of work for very little gain.